# What optimisations are done that this code completes quickly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I was solving a problem I came across, what is the sum of powers of 3 from 0 to 2009 mod 8.

I got an answer using pen and paper, and tried to verify it with some simple python

```
print(sum(3**k for k in range(2010)) % 8)
```

I was surprised by how quickly it returned an answer. My question is what optimisations or tricks are used by the interpreter to get the answer so quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only optimization at work is that each instance of `3**k` is evaluated using a number of multiplications proportional to the number of bits in `k` (it does *not* multiply 3 by itself `k-1` times).

As already noted, if you boost 2010 to 20100 or 201000 or ..., it will take much longer, because `3**k` becomes very large.  However, in those cases you can speed it enormously again by rewriting it as, e.g.,

```
print(sum(pow(3, k, 8) for k in range(201000)) % 8)
```

Internally, `pow(3, k, 8)` still does a number of multiplications proportional to the number of bits in `k`, but doesn't need to retain any integers internally larger than about 8**2 (the square of the modulus).

Answer (score 4):

None, it's just not a lot of computation for a computer to do.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
>>> a = sum(3**k for k in range(2010))
>>> a % 8
4
```

`a` is a 959-digit number - it's just not a large task to ask of a computer.

Try sticking two zeros on the end of the `2010` and you will see it taking an appreciable amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

No fancy optimizations are responsible for the fast response you observed. Computers are just a lot faster in absolute terms than you expected.